# Subscribers lost from AMQ broker

Tags: activemq-classic, broker

We are using AMQ 5.5.

It has been working perfectly since we upgraded from 5.3 to 5.5. But, this morning out of nowhere the broker started reporting a bunch of durable subscribers as inactive i.e. placed them under 'false' folder in 'Subscription' folder. And the 'Durable' and 'Non-Durable' folders under 'Subscription' went missing. Upon further investigation, we found that the subscribers marked as false (inactive) were actually subscribed to the resp. topics and were active.
Some publishers were also not able to publish messages.

We tried looking through activemq.log and kahadb.log files but nothing could be found. In the end we had to restart the broker to get it back to normal state.

Have you ever come across a situation like this before? Any thoughts on what could have caused this to happen?

Thank you in Advance.
Hari

Comment: Can someone please help me out with this. We were forced to restart our production broker instance with a lot of hesitation and so we would like to put any kind of fix around it to avoid this from happening again in the future.

ThanksHari

Answer (score 0):

This was caused due to memory space issues in the filer where data dir was present.